# Excess elements in array initializer

Tags: c++, c

I'm currently trying to print a table, but I keep getting an error that I have too many elements in my array initializer. What did I do wrong? (Using Xcode)

```
int coordinates[5] [2] = {{x1,x2,x3,x4,x5},{y1,y2,y3,y4,y5}};
```

Comment: `int coordinates[5][2]` wants five pairs as an initializer, not two groups of five. Perhaps you meant `int coordinates[2][5]`

Comment: Declare your array as "int coordinates[2][5]" => First number of lines, 2nd number of columns

Comment: sample [code](https://ideone.com/vDuTUp)

Answer (score 5):

```
int coordinates[5] [2]
```

is an array of *five arrays* of two `int` elements each.

Judging by your initialization, you want `coordinates` to be an array of *two* arrays of five `int` elements each:

```
int coordinates[2] [5]
```

Comment: I am actually trying to print a x,y coordinate table, should I still change it?

Comment: @IkejiriWilliam when you *print* data, the *print* code is responsible for formatting. When you *store/manipulate* data, it's better to design that in convenient and performant way. Coordinates are usually pair of values ([x, y]), so it makes more sense to store and manipulate them as pairs, then your `int coordinates[5][2]` sounds right. But your initializer then should reflect that: `{ {x1, y1}, {x2, y2}, ... };`. You can still format output any way you wish, in any case. Try to separate formatting/output code from definitions/manipulation code (MVC/MVP way of code structure design).

Comment: @IkejiriWilliam Perhaps you should take a look into *structures*? Closely related data is better handled by using a `struct`.

Answer (score 0):

Such an initializer used in an array declaration

```
{x1,x2,x3,x4,x5}
```

corresponds to a one-dimensional array that has at least 5 elements. However this declaration

```
int coordinates[5] [2] = { /*...*/ };
```

corresponds to an array elements of which are one-dimensional arrays of the type `int[2]`. So you may use an initializer list at most with two initializers to initialize each element of the two-dimensional array.

It seems that what you need is the following

```
int coordinates[5] [2] = 
{
    { x1, y1 }, 
    { x2, y2 }, 
    { x3, y3 }, 
    { x4, y4 }, 
    { x5, y5 } 
};
```